# What is the deference between 'ls -lh' and 'ls -si'?

Tags: linux, shell

I have executed both the comments but the size seems different in both output.

```
ls -lh
total 147M
-rw------- 1 root root 3.4K Sep 30 14:58 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  247 Sep 30 14:58 install.post.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   54 Sep 30 14:58 install.postnochroot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 147M Sep 30 14:58 jdk-7u79-linux-x64.gz

ls -l --si
total 154M
-rw------- 1 root root 3.5k Sep 30 14:58 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  247 Sep 30 14:58 install.post.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   54 Sep 30 14:58 install.postnochroot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 154M Sep 30 14:58 jdk-7u79-linux-x64.gz
```

Comment: what about checking `man ls`?

Comment: StackOverflow's purview is questions about programming. `ls` is a tool which shouldn't be used in a programmatic context (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Thus, it's not topical here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would have checked the manpage for ls with the command `man ls` you would have seen the following:

```
   -l     use a long listing format
   -h, --human-readable
          with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M
          2G)
   -i, --inode
          print the index number of each file
   -s, --size
          print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
```

So you see, each parameter just defines what and how information will be put to the screen. What you see (the difference in size) is the `-h` or `--human-readable` command, which will output more readable filesizes instead of printing always the bytes. Using `-s` will print the filesize in `blocks` on your HDD, which depends on the block size of your filesystem. From the information provided, i would say your filesystem has a `1kb` blocksize. So the real content of the file would be `3.4kb`, but must fill up the blocks, so on your disk the file requires `4kb` or `4 blocks` of space.

Comment: OP asked for the difference between -h and --si. The difference is that -h uses base-2 size calculations while using the base-10 prefixes, while --si uses base-10 for both calculating and displaying size, which is more correct.